# How to detect pen button press and release events

Tags: uwp

Is there any way to detect when user presses or releases button on the pen within APP?

Either the top button, or "right click" button on surface pen

Alternatively, how to detect, that the button is pressed when pen touches `InkCanvas`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may subscribe to **PointerPressed** event on InkCanvas. It has args **PointerRoutedEventArgs e**. Filter your input device and separate buttons like this:

```
if (e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Pen)
{
    var point = e.GetCurrentPoint(YourCanvasName);
    if (point.Properties.IsLeftButtonPressed)
    {
        //Button1
    }
    if (point.Properties.IsMiddleButtonPressed)
    {
        //Button2
    }
    if (point.Properties.IsRightButtonPressed)
    {
        //Button3
    }
}
```

Should work though i don't have a pen to test :)

Comment: I've tried both `inkCanvas.PointerPressed` and `InkCanvas.InkPresenter.UnprocessedInput.PointerPressed` bot none of them is triggered, neither when I press the button, nor when the pen touches the canvas with button pressed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `InkCanvas.InkPresenter.UnprocessedInput.PointerPressed` to work you got to set the `InkCanvas.InkPresenter.InputProcessingConfiguration.Mode` to `InkInputProcessingMode.None` but with that done your `InkCanvas` wont draw or erase any strokes anymore until you progrramed your own draw/erase method.